# history.go('url') issue

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-history

I've seen that history.go() method can have two types of parameter:

see:

```
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp
```

But url does not working at all.

I use JavaScript console of browser to test this method but got no success.

I know that there are security issues, that you can't read history entries. You can just go back and forward.

So why this string parameter listed in all js references?

Comment: Which browser and version are you trying this with?

Comment: Tried in Chrome latest and Mozilla firefox 4.1 or latest (whatever)..

Comment: w3schools is _not_ "all js references". It's _one_, particularly bad reference.

Comment: FWIW, I've found http://help.dottoro.com to be a better reference.  It's far from perfect but they do mention browser differences like this and offer a quick overview of browser support.  http://help.dottoro.com/ljhvjqec.php is their page for `history.go()`.

Comment: I raised this question because I see another bad reference ([here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/history.shtml)), so now learned that MDC is the best!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Supplying a URL as a parameter is a non-standard feature and will not work in all browsers.  Most browsers accept only a relative number, e.g. `1` or `-1`.

From the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history) (emphasis mine):

> [`history.go(integerDelta)`] Loads a page from the session history, identified by its relative location to the current page, for example -1 for the previous page or 1 for the next page. When `integerDelta` is out of bounds (e.g. -1 when there are no previously visited pages in the session history), the method doesn't do anything and doesn't raise an exception. **Calling `go()` without parameters or with a non-integer argument has no effect (unlike Internet Explorer, which supports string URLs as the argument)**.

This is what happens when you use [W3Schools](http://w3fools.com) as a learning resource ;-)

Comment: As a side note, if you want to go to a URL, use `window.location`

Answer (score 2):

[MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Moving_to_a_specific_point_in_history) at least has this note:

> Note: Internet Explorer supports passing string URLs as a parameter to go(); this is non-standard and not supported by Gecko.

No idea why it is listed in many references, though.

Comment: Probably because W3Schools shout about it. They have a lot more popularity than quality.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it with an URL just use:

```
window.location.href="http://www.whereyouwannago.nl/";
```

The URL is problably still there for backwards compatibility